# Powershell - Excel Change format of the column to Text

Tags: excel, powershell

I have to convert 2 columns in 20 excel files (same format) everyday. Is there a way in powershell to make it work. I searched for some examples but all point to change of Number format.

Current code:

```
$worksheet.columns.item('d').NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
```

The entire Workbook / Worksheet is in "General" format

Help is appreciated.

Comment: That is the correct property to set. Try passing it `@` for text formatting.

Comment: what is the command / syntax ?

Comment: This should be covered by the examples you've found. Please post your current code/attempt and I'll be happy to provide a more complete answer.

Comment: $worksheet.columns.item('d').NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"

Comment: `$worksheet.columns.item('d').NumberFormat = "@"`

Comment: Thanks ... that worked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per comments, you can use `@` to specify text formatting:

```
$worksheet.columns.item('d').NumberFormat = "@"
```